# How to make a counter in django html?

Tags: html, django, counter

I'm trying to have a counter that tell me how many time the first if (dato.tipo_cake == categoria) is true, so i can set lines of code when this value is 12 and 24, but the only thing that have a counter is the "for" and that count all the items not the items that have one type of attribute

```
{% for dato in cakes %}
    {% if dato.tipo_cake == categoria %}
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" ><a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ dato.imagen }}" class="thumbnail" title="{{ dato.titulo }}" data-gallery="blueimp-gallery"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ dato.thumbnail }}" alt="Thumb_{{ dato.titulo }}" width="240"></a>
        </div>
        {% if forloop.counter == 12 %}
            {{ forloop.counter }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
        {% endif %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 24 %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: [What are you trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: That code is part from a gallery, that depending of the tipo_cake, i can display it, i need to know how many times that condition is true, so i can have only 12 items it at the same time

Comment: You didn't read the article, did you.

Comment: Sorry i didn't know that your comment was a link, now i did. I still need something that help me to know how many time i show that link/imagen.

Comment: Why do you do that count in the view.py and then send the info to the template.

Comment: I can pass a counter, but how do i increment it?

Comment: no no, I mean, in the view, count how many types of cake there are, and pass that result to the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do any arithmetic operations on your template, but you can on views.py. So now your code should look something like this:

```
#views.py
def counter(request):
    n = 0
    for dato in cakes:
        if dato.tipo_cake == categoria:
            n += 1
    if n == 12:
        return render(request, 'Your_template.html', {"Counter_value":n})
    elif n == 24:
        # Return something also
```